# @sys-person is depreciated, how can I create a name entity for slots?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

IBM Watson Assistant is depreciating the @sys-person entity for some reason. I use it a lot in my slots to capture the name.

How can I create an entity that would do the same thing to replace @sys-person?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a supported language, use [annotation-based entities](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-entities#entities-annotations-overview).

The tutorial on [how to create a database-driven Slackbot](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html) uses that method for locations (**@sys-location** is deprecated, too). Load the provided skill and see how it is done.

Basically, you create an entity and then go to intent examples and tag the parts which identify a person. Then, Watson Assistant is learning that you expect a person entity in specific sentencens and sentence positions. You can fine-tune it by running some dialogs and correct the falsely identified or missing person entity values.

I use the same technique as replacement for @sys-location and it works for me in slots. Even "San Francisco" is recognized as one location. I added it as sample. You can tag entities across intents.

If you don't want to go that route, the only solution I am aware of is to define an entity, e.g., **my-person** with many examples and use that.

Comment: But the problem is I use it in a slot context. For example, my Bot asks "What name shall the reservation be under?" then the user responds "jay nguyen". I've tried the contextual entity and it doesn't work well, especially when the user inputs all the information at once.

Comment: What examples have you defined for that entity? Is it a training issue or how the dialog is defined?

Comment: @larrywalker using slot context works with Amazon Lex but not Watson. You have to create examples and annotate them. GIven names can exist in various formats you have to create examples for various name formats and annotate all of the names as @ name